# Modifying a label's text to display a function result after entering a screen in a python's kivy framework application

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I'm building simple android app using python kivy framework to classify handwritten digits using neural network. The app consists of three screens: main screen, camera screen that opens the camera and allows capturing a photo and saving it in the same directory, and a result screen that displays the result after feeding the image to a neural network. The problem is that I do not know how to edit this code so that upon capturing a photo and entering the results screen, the text of the 'label' in ResultScreen changes to display the result being computed from a function. Thanks in advance for help.
Here is the code:

````
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
import numpy as np
import pickle
import cv2
import time
import ANN
# load the trained model
trained_model = pickle.load(open('trained_model.sav', 'rb'))


screen_helper = """
ScreenManager:
    MenuScreen:
    CameraScreen:
    ResultScreen:
<MenuScreen>:
    name: 'menu'
    MDLabel:
        text: 'Digit Classifier'
        bold: True
        halign: 'center'
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text: 'Open Camera'
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.4}
        on_press: root.manager.current = 'camera'

<CameraScreen>:
    name: 'camera'
    orientation: 'vertical'
    padding_bottom: '100px'
    Camera:
        id: camera
        resolution: (400,400)
        play: True
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text: 'capture'
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.1}
        on_press: root.image_to_digit()
        on_press: root.manager.current = 'result'
        

        
<ResultScreen>:
    name: 'result'
    on_enter: root.displayResult()
    MDLabel:
        name:'label'
        text: ''
        halign: 'center'
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text: 'menu'
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.1}
        on_press: root.manager.current = 'menu'
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text: 'recapture'
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.2}
        on_press: root.manager.current = 'camera'
"""



class MenuScreen(Screen):
    pass


class CameraScreen(Screen, BoxLayout):

    def capture(self):
        camera = self.ids['camera']
        timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")
        pic_name = "IMG_{}.png".format(timestr)
        camera.export_to_png(pic_name)
        return pic_name


    def image_to_digit(self):
        '''Takes an image name as a parameter and uses the pre-trained model
        to predict the digit and return it as an integer'''
        # opens the image as an nd-array. The image file should be in the same
        # directory as that of main.py
        image = self.capture()
        img = cv2.imread(image, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

        # resize the image
        img = cv2.resize(img, (28, 28), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)

        # inverting the color of the picture (to match the trained set)
        img = cv2.bitwise_not(img)

        # reshaping image to fit to the network
        img = img.reshape((784, 1))

        # feeding the image to the model
        digit = trained_model.forward_propagation(img)
        result = open('result_file.txt','w')
        result.write(str(np.argmax(digit)))
        result.close()


class ResultScreen(Screen):
    def displayResult(self):
        result = open('result_file.txt','r')
        digit = result.read()
        result.close()


# Create the screen manager
sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(MenuScreen(name='menu'))
sm.add_widget(CameraScreen(name='camera'))
sm.add_widget(ResultScreen(name='result'))


class DemoApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        screen = Builder.load_string(screen_helper)
        
        return screen


DemoApp().run()```
````

Answer (score 1):

You can give the label an id 'result_label' in this case, then you can access the label's text by: self.ids['result_label'].text = "xyz"

```
"""  
<ResultScreen>:
   name: 'result'
   on_enter: root.displayResult()
   MDLabel:
       id: result_label
       name:'label'
       text: ''
       halign: 'center'
   MDRectangleFlatButton:
       text: 'menu'
       pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.1}
       on_press: root.manager.current = 'menu'
   MDRectangleFlatButton:
       text: 'recapture'
       pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.2}
       on_press: root.manager.current = 'camera'
"""






class ResultScreen(Screen):
   def displayResult(self):
       result = open('result_file.txt','r')
       digit = result.read()
       result.close()
       self.ids['result_label'].text = str(digit)
```